# The window identifier is not declared in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3, xcode8

I know that this question is a bit stupid, but can someone resolve this :
[image: Error]
I want to hide the title bar, but I want to keep the red green and yellow buttons. The file is ViewController.swift and I want to execute an action on  the main Window. The problem is that I can't create an Outlet from the window, P.S. I'm on Swift 3 with Xcode 8

Comment: Add prefersStatusBarHidden method

Comment: But how ? @EricAya